# mvn release:prepare doesn't work using maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

My JAVA_HOME is properly set up to `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_01`

```
$echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_01

$sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java             1         manual mode
  3            /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_01/bin/java             1         manual mode
```

I am using mvn release:prepare plugin to produce the git tag and flip project's version in the pom.xml. It works perfect if I use maven 2.2.1 When I use maven 3.0.4, I get:

```
[INFO] Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
[INFO]   We cannot execute /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java/bin/java
```

I guess there might be a bug in maven 3, when it runs, it tries to append `/bin/java` twice to my JAVA_HOME.

Comment: are you sure that you didn't set the path to bin directory? or is there bin directory present in your JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: @ant echo $JAVA_HOME shows it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the standard Oracle/Sun JDK, if that is an option at all. I have hit this myself before on Debian/Ubuntu. I never had the patience to figure out what was wrong with the OpenJDK, but it doesn't cope well with Maven. Or... at least... such was my observation.

Comment: I am using oracle JDK. Switched back to maven 2.2, works perfect :(

Comment: Show us the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME && echo $PATH && which java && java -version`.

Comment: Also show the output of `ls -al $JAVA_HOME && ls -al \`which java\``

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME must point to jre, then set :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_01/jre
```

Answer (score 0):

Search JAVA_HOME in your mvn command file (use `which mvn` to find it).
Mine does handle the JAVA_HOME if not already defined.

So perhaps you can get around it by `unset JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

**remove** the file in **old** maven home and it will change to new one.

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.1/libexec /usr/local/Cellar/maven_bak
```

before that, you need to export your jdk and maven firstly. and how to do this, you can see following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715235/11679986