# change maven java version 1.7 to 1.6 in ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

how can change my maven java version from 1.7.0_55 to java-1.6.0
two java vesions installed in my system

```
1-java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 
2-java-7-oracle 1062 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-orac
```

when i run mvn -version result is

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Please help me..I am new to these things...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven might help.

Comment: how can open and edit mavenrc file in ubuntu..I am beginer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set JAVA_HOME to which ever version you want in your bash_profile.

`Maven uses JAVA_HOME to read the Java version to be used`

Comment: I changed the JAVA_HOME path using JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::") but still getting same error..

Comment: sorry reddy..now my maven java version changed.but when I give mvn clean install ..I am getting error.could you please help me??