# Error in Maven build: mvn.bat not recognized

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, netbeans

While trying to build a Java project under NetBeans (with an external Maven configured), I got the following error:

> "C:\Users......\bin\mvn.bat"" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

**Edit**: Using Maven 3.3.3, Windows 10;
Added custom maven to NetBeans under Tools > Options > Java > Maven > Execution > Maven Home > Browse

What can I do?

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of data. What's the version of Maven you're using? What operating system are you using? How did you configure the external Maven in NetBeans?

Comment: Looks like a quotes issue in the path specification for `mvn.bat`; how exactly is the path given?

Comment: thanks for the help but meanwhile I solved it: please checkout my answer bellow. regarding the path, it is given by the browse... http://prntscr.com/8j5w5m

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To solve it:

1. Go to the Maven installation folder
2. Go to `bin`
3. Make sure you can see file extensions
4. Duplicate `mvn.cmd` and `mvnDebug.cmd` and rename those copies to have the extension `.bat`
5. Try building the project now

[source](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251380#c1)

Comment: The issue is only a problem with maven 3.3.3+ (maven removed .bat file and replaced it with .cmd - support for win9x dropped) and is solved since Netbeans 8.1 beta I believe.

Comment: hmm interesting. still, most of the people are probably not using beta version of NetBeans so I thought it can be useful for them.

Comment: I agree. I only wanted to point out that it's a backward incompatible change in maven that affects any netbeans version smaller than 8.1 beta. (likely other tools as well)

Answer (score 2):

Install Netbeans 8.1 or later to correct this [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251213).

As @mkleint [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32706001/4252741), this is a problem with Maven 3.3.3+ where maven changed the mvn executable extension.You can [download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) the latest version on the Netbeans website.

Answer (score 1):

Maven 3.3+ has no more mvn.bat you should use version 2.5.2+ of the maven-release-plugin : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-902

Answer (score 0):

For Maven 3.6+ only duplicate and rename the mvn.cmd file from within your maven installation build folder