# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags when using lombok

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-plugin, lombok

I have following dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.8</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, I have following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass (ClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:566)
    at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass (ShadowClassLoader.java:418)
```

I tried to use java `1.8, 1.9, 1.10`. And I tried lombok `1.6.10, 1.6.12, 1.6.20`. All of them have the same problem.

Comment: Check the compatiability between Java and lombok and download those version and run it again.

Comment: I had this issue with the Java version >10, verify if you are using the correct version of Java.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem in my maven project with any Java-8+ version and Lombok 1.18.2 version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Same issue, I had version `1.16.X`. Increasing the version fixed it

Comment: I had to reload Jetbrains to download the new version

Answer (score 16):

I had changed the `lombok` version and it worked for me.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem and I solve it by adding this code in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think your artifactId should be `lombok` not `lombok-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 7):

Solved the issue by upgrading lombok version from 1.16.18 to 1.16.22 . I suspect any compatible version higher than .22 might do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

my project uses java1.8,and this problem have be solved by using lombok 1.18.4.

Comment: Please update your answer. [English is required on stack overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)

Answer (score 6):

This happened with me when I installed `maven` with brew which also installed Java.15.x that leads to this error.

To validate, add debug option `-X` while building with maven and check the Java version that maven is using.

Delete the Java.15x directory and set JAVA_HOME in your `.bashrc` with the correct version of Java.

Comment: quite similar here, trying to build the application on IntelliJ, the IDE is configured with the Java8 JDK, but there is a Java11 JDK on the JAVA_HOME.... so the build failed with this exact error message.
Updating the Lombok version works too, but for me, the right fix was just fix the JAVA_HOME content to the right JDK

Answer (score 5):

Solved this by:

1) download the lombok-edge.jar,

2) using following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.21</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/Users/xxx/Downloads/lombok-edge.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I always managed to resolve this issue with numerous old projects using older version of Lombok by simply upgrading the Lombok version

With this upgrade of Lombok; for projects with heavy memory during test running phases I have also had to start specifying memory configurations for `maven-surefire-plugin` which generally seems to now need more memory to avoid `Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?`
 errors

See below for example working pom.xml configs

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  </properties>
    ...
    <lombok.version>1.18.2</lombok.version>
    ...
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!--Extra memory to prevent jvm crash during heavy Integration/unit test with newer lombok and jdk8-->
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following lombok dependency on java-1.8 and java-11, and it build successfully.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when upgrading my project from JDK 8 to JDK 12 and using gradle instead of maven and using the `io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok` gradle plugin to configure lombok automatically.

In this scenario changing buildScript.dependencies from `classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:1.14"` to `classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:3.2.0"` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Java 8 and had my lombok dependency with no version at all. ALl i did was downgrade the lombok version to an older one, enough to be compatible with my Spring Boot 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Just check at: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok and choose newer version. For me using `<version>1.18.24</version>` fixed the problem