# Java maven installing issue in intellij

Tags: java, maven, installation, microservices

I downloaded several types of microservices, I initially run `mvn clean` and `mvn install -DskipTests`. All these time it occurred below build failure.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-09T10:04:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/130M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project invoice-microservice: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My maven version : `Apache Maven 3.5.2`

Maven home: `/usr/share/maven`

Java version: `10.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation`

Java home: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

Default locale: `en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8`

OS name: `"linux", version: "4.15.0-44-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: I think you need to install Lombok. Please check this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760733/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-tools-javac-code-typetags-w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)

Comment: I tried it. But it not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to give JDK path instead of JRE in installed JREs as below, Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE ->Edit

[image]