# Where to add JAVA_HOME and MAVEN path variables in linux

Tags: java, linux, maven

I know there are a lot of articles about this topic but I wonder where to add the JAVA_HOME and MAVEN path variables.

I have 3 files:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
/etc/profile
```

Which one should I use in order to add JAVA_HOME and export maven to the PATH?

```
export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I personally use ~/.bashrc but I don't believe that they are strict rules for this

Comment: With java installed to a system location, and to /etc/alternatives/ , you never have to think about setting JAVA_HOME.

Comment: If you installed different versions of Java installed JDK6, JDK7, JDK8, JDK9 than you have to think about that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only thing to do is to add the `bin` folder of the appropriate Maven distribution (`apache-maven-3.3.9/bin`) to your path variable. The `JAVA_HOME` location can be done either via environment variable. But the problem here is that it might influence other tools etc. So i would suggest to use `$HOME/.mavenrc` file for such purposes.

A `.mavenrc` file can look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/...LocationYouNeed
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx768m ..."
```

By using this you can limit this only to Maven. So in the end you only need to set the location of Maven via `PATH` that's it.

Starting with [Maven 3.3.1](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) you can use the `.mvn/jvm.config` to configure memory settings etc. on a per project base which will be checked in with your project. This means you can remove the `MAVEN_OPTS` from your `.mavenrc` file.

Usually you don't necessarily need to add `JAVA_HOME/bin` to your path. If you need `JAVA_HOME` only to run Maven you don't need to.

If you need to support multiple Maven versions you can define a location in your path which you can change via a symbolic link.