# Change Java Version from 1.8 to 1.6 in maven project in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Right now I have the maven dependencies project with Java 1.8 in Intellij but due to business requirement I have to convert the project in the Java 1.6.
Can you please let me know how and what are the changes I have to make in order to change the version of Java from 1.8 to 1.6?

Regards,
Dheeraj

Comment: Hire a developer with java knowledge?

Comment: Please refer to the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven

Comment: Note that you should not use java 1.6 (it's an old version)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.