# maven complie error: cannot access a jar

Tags: java, scala, maven, jar

When I compile use idea, I meet this problem.
I use mac 10.12.6
idea 2017.2.4
The compile command I use is "mvn -e clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true"

This error info maybe say cannot access netlib-native_system-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar, but I confirm there is the jar in my .m2 repository.

This is the whole error message. I delete some useless line.

```
[ERROR] error while loading <root>, Error accessing /Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/netlib/netlib-native_system-linux-armhf/1.1/netlib-native_system-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] angel .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.311 s]
[INFO] angel-ps ........................................... SUCCESS [  4.242 s]
[INFO] angel-ps-core ...................................... FAILURE [  3.642 s]
[INFO] angel-ps-psf ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project angel-ps-core: wrap: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project angel-ps-core: wrap: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: wrap: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:99)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:184)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:164)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:92)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :angel-ps-core
```

Comment: can you re-run it with `-e` and post output here

Comment: @JigarJoshi, I have re-run use "mvn -e clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using Java 9 as Scala does not support it yet.

"We are planning to add (some) support for Java 9 in the near future. Full Java 9 support will be part of the 2.13 roadmap discussions."

(source: http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#java-8-runtime)

Comment: I use jdk8 and scala 2.11

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue also and I did this to fix.

you need to reinstall your maven and jdk in your home path, not in the root home, because some **jar cannot be used by some permission problems**. so you need to move you jdk and related jar packages to another path you definitely have permission.

and how to change jdk and maven you can click this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715235/11679986