# How to find local Java path from pom.xml in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, variables, path

I'm currently working on a Maven project. In my pom.xml, I have to specify my local path for JDK as following :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_202. But my colleague, whom I work with on the project, uses Java 1.8.0_144. Is there a way to variablize the local Java path so that we don't have to modify it each time we get one another's modifications on the code from Git?

Comment: First question would be: why do you have to specify the path to your JDK in your POM file? There should be no need for that in a typical project.

Comment: User dependent settings are in general in [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

For the local java in pom.xml concern you can use refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven/19654699), This already covers how maven works. But your concern about Git, you can use `.gitignore` command to ignore changes in pom.xml file refer to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/learning-how-to-git-ignoring-files-and-folders-using-gitignore-177556afdbe3).