# How to fix 'Unsupported class file major version 55' while executing 'org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet.collectAsList()'

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I'm creating a Java RESTAPI Spring Boot application that uses spark to get some data from the server. When I try to convert from Dataset to List it fails.

I've tried jdk8 and jdk11 to compile and execute the code but I get the same 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55', in the past, I've solved this issue by updating Java version, but it's not working for this.

I'm using:

- JDK 11.0.2
- Spring Boot 2.1.4
- Spark 2.4.2

This is the code I'm executing:

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sparkSession.read().json("/home/data/*.json");
        dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("events");
        Dataset<Row> resultDataFrame = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM events WHERE " + predicate); 
        Dataset<Event> eventDataSet = resultDataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(Event.class));
        return eventDataSet.collectAsList();
```

The query works, actually while debugging you can see information in both resultDataFrame and eventDataSet.

I expect the output to be a proper list of Events, but I'm getting the exception:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
.....
```

UPDATE BY COMMENTS:
For Java 8, I change pom to aim java 8:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

And then update project, maven clean, maven install and then run.
Getting same version 55 error

Comment: This suggest the ASM version used by Apache XBean (see the stacktrace) doesn't support Java 11.

Comment: It doesn't work with Java 8 either, and I don't see anything in the stack trace... other weird thing is that it only happens with some of the methods, not all of them

Comment: To run on Java 8 you will need to compile with Java 8 or at least targeting Java 8.

Comment: I've already tried with java8 and it doesn't work

Comment: If you used Java 8, then it wouldn't be saying "version 55" anymore, so can you descibe how you "tried" to use it?

Comment: edited in the question :)

Comment: looke here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven/19654699

Comment: in spring boot applications you change java version in pom with <java.version> property, that should be enough (at least it always have been)

Comment: I'm running it with eclipse, the JDK configured for this project is 1.8, is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: are you sure your POM file is correct? - please look at the comment from @matanper  which shows how to set the java version in maven

Comment: first of all is not recommended to convert from dataset to list (heap is very limited) then you need to be sure that your classes are compiled with the same version of objects in spark cluster, so you need an appropriate version of jdk on your machine (not only as a maven property), and you need that jdk to compile your classes

Comment: I fixed it, as someone mentioned (I think that comment has been deleted now) the issue was in my local path, I had JAVA_HOME aiming a symbolic link that I forgot that I changed to another version, it's fixed now. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @GJCode, I know it's not recommended, but it needs to return the data to the request. The results have been filtered previously, so it shouldn't give any issues, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of the issue was a symbolic link that I have aiming the wrong JDK and that's why it wasn't working. JAVA_HOME was aiming a jdk11 and eclipse was running with that.

Comment: It was gradle jvm version setting for me

Answer (score 19):

Excluding the default XBean artifact from spark-core dependency and adding latest version of XBean artifact, it worked for me.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-asm6-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
                <artifactId>xbean-asm6-shaded</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This was the savior. 

Comment: This resolved my problem to.@ManoshP How did you reach to this conclusion to remove this artifact and add latest version.

Comment: This solution solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Using org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.8 with Java 11 and encountered this issue. The suggested solution worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since most `python` developers spawn out virutalenv for the project, you could use the below snippet to check the versions of different components required for `pyspark` to work. The reason for the error is incompatible java version. `pyspark` expects `java version 1.8+` and not `jdk-11`. `Major version 55` corresponds to `jdk-11` as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

Check the official spark documentation only for version compatibility.

```
import subprocess

# subprocess to find the java , scala and python version
cmd1 = "java -version"
cmd2 = "scala -version"
cmd3 = "python --version"
cmd4 = "whoami"

arr = [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4]

for cmd in arr:
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
    stdout,stderr=process.communicate()
    logging.info(stdout.decode("utf-8") + " | "  + stderr.decode("utf-8"))

logging.info(os.getenv("JAVA_HOME"))
logging.info(os.getenv("HOME"))
```

You will get the below output:

```
INFO:root: | openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

INFO:root: | Scala code runner version 2.12.2 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

INFO:root:Python 3.6.9

INFO:root:training
```