# Spark Streaming Kafka with Java11 scala code Issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, java-11

I am using scala Spark Streaming Kafka with JDK 11. But I am getting the below error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;

Below is the code I am using.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaExample")
      .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.table_data")
      .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.table_data")
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false")
      .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")

val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")
    val topics = List("topic").toSet
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.8</version><!--<version>2.3.2</version>-->
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.8</version><!--<version>2.3.2</version>-->
          <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
     
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.10.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

The issue is coming in `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()` and i checked the maven and scala compatibility JDK 11 is compatible with scala 2.12 and higher and we don't have any maven dependency for `spark-streaming-kafka` jar. KIndly let me know if my analysis is wrong and which jar should i use for `spark-streaming-kafka` for JDK 11

Comment: spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 will not work with scala 2.12. 2.11 and 2.12 are not binary compatible. Maybe you need to use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 which target's 2.12

[is your Kafka broker >0.10](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#content) ?

Comment: My kafka version is kafka_2.13-2.6.0 is it greater than 0.10. Also when i use the jar dependency you have suggested, It will require a lot of code change in KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() is it necessary?

Comment: Got help from here and got the issue resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923943/how-to-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55-while-executing-org-apache

Answer (score 0):

1. DirectStream API is deprecated, you should be using spark-sql-kafka-0-10 dependencies. The Mongo Spark driver works with Spark SQL also
2. As commented, you're mixing your Scala versions (the broker Scala version doesn't matter), and you're also mixing your Spark versions