# How to switch java version easily like SDKMAN and JENV on windows

Tags: java, windows, sdk, environment-variables, sdkman

I am using,

- jdk 8
- jdk 11
- jdk 17
- jdk 21
  But in different project they use different jdk versions, everytime i go to environmental variables and change.

I tried `jenv` but it's kinda irritating, i used sdkman in ubunut it works nice,
please any help me to solve this issue, Is there any alternatives like `sdkman` or `jenv` or tell me how to use `sdkman` in windows

Comment: There are quite a few good options for doing this here. This link is intended for Maven, but the concept should work for Gradle or other tools:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven